# Refreshing annotations mix photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

First time the view controller load, I download data from web service, then use the details to add annotations.
When I tap the button to download again the data and put in all over again, wrong photos each and every time.
I tried to clear the cache and it doesn't help, I tried a lot of ways.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
- (void)addCustomersToMap
{
    marker = nil;
    profilePics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([self.usersNearMe isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *singleUser = (NSDictionary*)self.usersNearMe;
        self.usersNearMe = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:singleUser, nil];
    }
    if ([self.usersNearMe isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        for (int  i = 0; i < self.usersNearMe.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *dict = self.usersNearMe[i];
            float lat = [[dict objectForKey:@"Lat"] floatValue];
            float lon = [[dict objectForKey:@"Lon"] floatValue];
            NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
            NSString *time = [dict objectForKey:@"Time"];
            NSString *picUrl = [dict objectForKey:@"PictureUrl"];
            [profilePics addObject:picUrl];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D mLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);


            if ([picUrl isEqualToString:@"empty"])
            {
                marker = [[CustomerMarker alloc] initWithLocation:mLoc title:name andSubtitle:time andUrlString:nil andImagePerson:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user"]];
            }
            else if ([picUrl isEqualToString:@"system"])
            {
                marker = [[CustomerMarker alloc] initWithLocation:mLoc title:name andSubtitle:time andUrlString:nil andImagePerson:[UIImage imageNamed:@"police_icon"]];
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *completeURL = @"";
                completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:kPROFILE_IMAGE_URL];
                completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:@"/2/"];
                completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:picUrl];
                completeURL = [completeURL stringByAppendingString:@".png"];


                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:completeURL];
                NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
                    if (responseData) {
                        NSString  *imageName = completeURL.lastPathComponent;
                        NSString *imagePath = [[self documentsDirectoryPath] stringByAppendingString:imageName];
                        NSLog(@"imagePath: %@", imagePath);
                        [responseData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
                        marker = [[CustomerMarker alloc] initWithLocation:mLoc title:name andSubtitle:time andUrlString:nil andImagePerson:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [self.btnRefreshUsers setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            [self.mapView viewForAnnotation:marker];
                            [self.mapView addAnnotation:marker];
                        });
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }

    self.btnRefreshUsers.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}



- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            [self.mapView selectAnnotation:((MKUserLocation*) annotation) animated:YES];
        }
    });

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        ((MKUserLocation*) annotation).title = NSLocalizedString(@"current_location", nil);
        return nil;
    }

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomerMarker class]])
    {
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
        static NSString *customerMarkerPinID = @"com.idm.customer";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:customerMarkerPinID];

        if (!pinView)
        {
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:customerMarkerPinID];
        }

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


        CustomerMarker *customerMarker = (CustomerMarker*)annotation;
        pinView.image = customerMarker.imagePerson;

        CGRect pinViewFrame = CGRectZero;
        pinViewFrame.origin.x = pinView.frame.origin.x;
        pinViewFrame.origin.y = pinView.frame.origin.y;
        pinViewFrame.size.width = 40.0f;
        pinViewFrame.size.height = 40.0f;
        pinView.frame = pinViewFrame;


        ////////// Animate Pin Drop //////////

        CGRect endFrame = pinView.frame;
        pinView.frame = CGRectOffset(pinView.frame, 0, -230);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.45f];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        pinView.frame = endFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        /* CGRect endFrame = pinView.frame;
        pinView.frame = CGRectOffset(pinView.frame, 0, -230);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews animations:^{
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                pinView.frame = endFrame;
            }
        }]; */

        return pinView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major problems here. First you're reusing a pinView but not setting the attributes according to the annotation that it is trying to draw. You're correct to dequeue a reusable annotationView, but if you reuse one or don't you will always need to set the image to the one you want to draw right now otherwise the pinView's image will be the one that it was previously. e.g.

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomerMarker class]])
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;//Create a new handle, don't risk having one global one
    static NSString *customerMarkerPinID = @"com.idm.customer";
    pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:customerMarkerPinID];

    if (!pinView)
    {
        pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:customerMarkerPinID];

        //Since all your pinViews can show callouts you only need to set this
        //when creating a new one, not when reusing an existing one which will
        // already have it set
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
        pinView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pic"]];

    ...   

    return pinView;
}

//[self.mapView setNeedsDisplay];  <--- Don't do this
return nil;
```

Secondly you're choosing the image for each pin based on `profilePicsCounter` which is changed while you're adding the images but the *mapView can and will ask for the views in any order it feels like* not the order you add them. So you need to respond to `viewForAnnotation` by calculating the view based on the annotation it gives you. The clue is in the name. 
This line:

```
NSString *urlString = profilePics[profilePicsCounter];
```

Needs to be something like

```
MyAnnotationClass *myAnno = (MyAnnotationClass)annotation
NSString *urlString = myAnno.urlString;
```

Essentially you've got to store the info it needs within the annotation.

Also, the annotations part of `removeAllMarkers` function can be shortened to one line

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
```

And you're setting the backgroundColor on your pinViews twice

Comment: Thanks for your help, as faster as I will check it with few more annotations, I'll mark your answer as correct, right now I've only 1 person as an annotation.

Comment: OK, photos still get mixed up.

Comment: @IdanMoshe: As already stated in the answer: "you're reusing a pinView but not setting the attributes according to the annotation that it is trying to draw...".  The updated code is still only setting the annotation's image when a new view is created but not when one is being re-used.  It needs to set the image regardless (because the image is based on the _current_ `annotation`).